# 403 forbidden error on upload file to server

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

How to upload file to an external server using HTML5?

Im using the below code for uploading the file.

```
var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);
        xhr.open("POST", "http://anotherdomain/Upload.aspx");
        xhr.send(fd);
```

I'm getting error 403(forbidden) in fiddler.

Can anyone provide some insight on this?

Comment: The external server could be returning 403 error if you have no permission or you are sending invalid data to them. Have you referred to any documentation given by the provider of the external server?

Comment: The URL path is valid and i verified it. Using HTML5 its possible to upload to external server without any cross domain issue?

Comment: I don't mean the URL path is invalid (you would probably receive 404 instead if this is the case), but you could be not conforming their API or anything, so I suggest you to read their doc. I don't think cross domain play any role for file uploading in your case.

Comment: for clarifying this i just created another application in my system and from my source application (for eg:http://myip/test.aspx) submitted to http://localhost/client/upload.aspx. Im getting the same error now.

Comment: This indicates something wrong in either what you sent or the server configuration, I think...

Comment: so using HTML5 can we avoid cross domain issue and there are no chances to get errors like this? if im submitting to the same domain i'm able to post the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47673/discussion-between-luiges90-and-user833985)